# Serilog message to azure log stream

Tags: logging, serilog

I have been using .net core inbuilt ILogger class to log messages to Application insights. I was able to see the log message in the Azure log stream. Now I have changed to Serilog for structured logging. The message are logged to application insights, however I don't see them in Azure's log stream as it happend for when used .net core inbuild ILogger.

Below is the configuration in host.json file.

```
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "console": {
      "isEnabled": "true"
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Debug"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" ],
    "MinimumLevel": { 
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning",
        "Host": "Warning",
        "EIP": "Debug", 
       
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "===> {Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": false
      }
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:05:00"
}
```

Extension method for serilog logging

```
public static IServiceCollection AddLogging(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var telemetryConfig = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
            telemetryConfig.InstrumentationKey = configuration.GetValue<string>("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY");
            
             Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                             .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration, "AzureFunctionsJobHost:Serilog")
                             .Destructure.ToMaximumCollectionCount(200)
                             .Destructure.ToMaximumDepth(8)
                             .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(telemetryConfig, new TraceTelemetryConverter(), Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)
                             .CreateLogger();
            services.AddLogging(lb =>
            {
                lb.AddSerilog(Log.Logger, true);
            });
            return services;
        }
```

Below is the log stream I am referring too

[image]

Any suggestions to fix this issues?

Comment: What have you tried, what does your config look like, what do you see in a debugger? Better to give that context in your question so someone familiar with the relevant bits can answer without having to guess all the stuff you are leaving unsaid. (Not familiar with Azure tooling but you need to define 'the Azure log stream')

Comment: @RubenBartelink. I have update the question, I hope it provides some context.

Comment: +1 for whats now a good question. I know zilch about that env so can't really help personally (though I'd strip it down to the most basic code only config first)

Comment: @venkateshk did you figure this out?  I've recently added the serilog and noted same behavior where I no longer see Log stream. My thoughts are that the new log config clobbers the existing. If only I could log the existing before I configure the new?

Comment: @AdamCox, I tried at multiple places, tried different configuration, in azure app. Nothing worked.